# Derivative of distance function on a Riemannian manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

While reading Andrews and Hopper's book on Ricci flow, I found the following computation which I am not able to verify.

$M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold and $p \in M$ and $r>0$. We are interested in the function $\psi(x) = \phi\left(\frac{d_{g}(x,p)}{r}\right)$. Here $\phi$ is a smooth bump function $\phi: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties.

1. $\phi = 1$ on $[0,1/2]$.
2. $\phi = 0$ on $[1,\infty)$.
3. $|\phi'| \leq 3$ on $[1/2,1]$.

Now we want to compute the derivative of $\psi$. Claim is that $|\nabla \psi| \leq \frac{1}{r} \sup |\phi'|$.

I assumed $r$ is small enough so that $B(p,r)$ lies in a normal neighborhood around $p$, then $d_{g}(p,x)= \sqrt{x_{1}^{2} + \dots + x_{n}^{2}}$ in normal coordinates around $p$. Then I see that
$$
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_{i}} = \frac{1}{r}\phi'\left( \frac{d_{g}(x,p)}{r}\right) \frac{x_{i}}{\sqrt{x_{1}^{2} + \dots + x_{n}^{2}}}.
$$

Thus
$$
|\nabla \psi|^{2} = g^{ij}(x)\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_{i}} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_{j}} = \frac{1}{r^{2}}\phi'\left(\frac{d_{g}(x,p)}{r}\right)^{2}\frac{g^{ij}(x)x_{i}x_{j}}{x_{1}^{2} + \dots + x_{n}^{2}}.
$$

I don't know how to go forward. I tried working in normal coordinates around $x$, that didn't seem to work either.

Also, I am not sure how to deal with the derivative of the distance function if $x$ is not in a normal neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: If $x$ is not in a normal neighborhood of $p$, $d$ might not be differentiable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another more intuitive (and coordinate free) way to see this: Since $\psi (x) = \phi \left( \frac{d(x, p)}{r}\right)$,
$$\nabla \psi = \phi' \left(\frac{d(x, p)}{r}\right) \cdot \frac{\nabla d}{r}$$

So it suffices to show that $|\nabla d|\le 1$. This follows from triangle inequality: Let $v\in T_xM$. Then $\gamma (t) = \exp_x (tv)$ is a curve on $M$ with $\gamma(0) = x$, $\gamma'(0) = v$. Then

\begin{align*}
\langle \nabla d, v\rangle &= \frac{d}{dt} d(p, \gamma(t))\bigg|_{t=0} \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{d(p, \gamma(t)) - d(p, x)}{t}
\end{align*}

Since by triangle inequality,
$$\left|\frac{d(p, \gamma(t)) - d(p, x)}{t}\right| \le \frac{d(x, \gamma(t))}{|t|} = \frac{|t|\| v\|}{|t|} = \|v\|$$

we have
$$ |\langle \nabla d, v\rangle| \le \|v\|\Rightarrow |\nabla d| \le 1$$

(e.g. by picking $v = \nabla d$).

We use nothing but that the distance function $d(\cdot, p)$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $1$. This already implies that the gradient is $\le 1$.

Comment: This is slightly incomplete, because it doesn't make sense to talk about the gradient of $d$ at points inside the cut locus (which might intersect $B_p(2r) \setminus B_p(r)$), since it's not differentiable there. Since we want to define $\psi$ on the whole of $M$, your answer only proves (indirectly) that there exists $r_0 > 0$ small enough such that $\psi = 1$ on the ball of radius $r_0$, $\psi = 0$ outside the ball of radius $2 r_0$ and $\nabla \psi$ is bounded as desired. The biggest such $r_0$ is the injectivity radius of $M$, which might also be $0$ and hence depend on the fixed point $p$

Comment: I pointed that out already in the comment. The function IS not differentiable, and this answer shows that $|\nabla \psi|$ is bounded at the point where $\psi$ is differentiable. @MatheusAndrade

Comment: Sorry, I read your answer (which doesn't mention this issue) before I read your comment, I just thought it would be good if you had added it to your answer as well, but in the end it really doesn't matter. Thanks for the answer by the way!

Answer (score 5):

The answers above of course do the job. Another nice way to prove that the gradient of the distance function has norm one is to use the first variation formula, and like Arctic Char's answer, this also works at all points where the distance function is differentiable. Moreover one gets an explicit formula for the gradient as the velocity vector of a minimal unit speed geodesic. It is well known that the distance function $d_p(x):= d(p,x)$ is differentiable precisely at those points $x\in M\setminus \{p\}$ which can be connected to $p$ be a unique minimal geodesic. For simplicity let us just work away from the cut locus so that $d_p$ is in fact smooth. Suppose $x$ is one such point and $\gamma_x:[0,d_p(x)]\rightarrow M$ is the unique unit speed minimal geodesic from $p$ to $x$. Then we claim that $$\nabla d_p (x) = \gamma_x'(d_p(x)).$$ In particular, $|\nabla d_p(x)| = 1$ since $\gamma_x$ is chosen to be unit speed. Let us now prove the claim. Let $v\in T_xM$ be an arbitrary unit vector. Since the cut-locus is closed, there exists a $\sigma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\rightarrow M$ such that $\sigma(0) = x$, $\sigma'(0) = v$ and such that there exists a unique minimal geodesic $\gamma_{s}:[0,d_p(x)]\rightarrow M$ from $p$ to $\sigma(s)$ for all $s\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. Then $\Gamma(s,t) = \gamma_s(t)$ is a variation of $\gamma(t)$ through geodesics. Moreover $\Gamma(s,0) = p$ for all $s$. We now compute
\begin{align*}
\langle\nabla d_p(x),v\rangle &= \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0}d_p(\sigma(s))\\
& = \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0}\mathcal{L}(\gamma_s)\\
&= \langle \dot\gamma(d_p(x)),v\rangle + \int_0^{d_p(x)}\langle\mathcal{D}_t\gamma_x,v\rangle\\
&= \langle \dot\gamma(d_p(x)),v\rangle.
\end{align*}
Here $\mathcal{L}$ is the length functional and we use the first variation formula in the third line. This shows that $$\langle\nabla d_p(x),v\rangle =\langle \dot\gamma(d_p(x)),v\rangle $$ for all unit tangent vectors $v\in T_xM$ and hence the claim is proved.

Comment: Id like to suggest an idea based on similar intuition. Near the point $x$, can we consider a submanifold consisting of all points where $d_p(y)=d_p(x).$ Then if we know that this will form an $n-1$ dimensional submanifold, then we can give a a basis of $T_xM$ consisting of $\gamma '(x)$ along with the basis of the mentioned submanifold. Then it is easy to show that along that submanifold $d_p$ will have zero derivatives. Then all only in the direction of $\gamma '(x)$ it changes. Will it work?

Comment: None of the answers in this post actually solve the problem completely. Since we want to define $\psi$ on the whole of $M$, your simplicity assumption that we're working away from the cut locus actually makes us lose all generality!

Comment: @MatheusAndrade $\psi$ is defined everywhere on $M$. Just that it is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @ArcticChar when I read the original post I thought we wanted a function $\psi$ which is differentiable everywhere on $M$ and satisfies the desired estimates (and for a paper I'm reading, it actually comes up that we do want a $\psi$ differentiable everywhere), so in that sense the answers are incomplete, but since the OP left it ambiguous it's really a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

You've almost completed the computation. The last step is noting that in normal coordinates the radial vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}=\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is a has unit magnitude (because it is the velocity of a unit speed geodesic). Thus, the second term in your expression $\frac{g^{ij}x_ix_j}{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}$ is equal to $1$.