# Norm of the differential of a Lipschitz function on a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $f\colon M\to\mathbb{C}$ a smooth function. Suppose that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz in the sense that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq Ld(x,y)$$
for all $x,y\in M$, where $d$ is the Riemannian distance function.

**Question:** Is it true that $\|df(x)\|\leq L$ for all $x\in M$, where the norm refers to the norm on $T^*_xM$ induced by the Riemannian metric?

If $M$ were a normed vector space, then we can prove this by writing the derivative of $f$ as a limit, but how does one proceed on a manifold?

Comment: Hint: Write your $f$ and the metric in local coordinates near the given point in $M$.

Comment: One can argue similarly using my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3787569/629362)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi = (y^1,...,y^n)$ be normal coordinates around $x$. Then write $df(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^i}(x)dy^i(x)$. Let $\nu = \sum_{i=1}^n \nu_i \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}(x) \in T_x M$ with $||\nu|| = 1$. Then $|df(x)(\nu)| = |\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^i}(x)dy^i(x)(\nu)| = |\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^i}(x)\nu_i| = |\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f\circ \varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x) + t\nu)- f(x)}{t}| \leq \limsup_{t \to 0} \frac{Ld(\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x) + t\nu), x)}{|t|} = \limsup_{t \to 0}\frac{L||\varphi(x)+t\nu - \varphi(x)||}{|t|} = L$.

As $\nu \in T_x M, ||\nu|| = 1$ was arbitrary, we get $||df(x)|| \leq L$.